# Acumatica Change to a Description field to Dropdown list, does not work

Tags: acumatica

In the Sales Orders->Discounts Details Tab, I have changed an existing field (Description) to a dropdown.

The LAYOUTPROPERTIES Type is set to "DropDownList".
The Control is set to "ComboBox"
The StringList is as follows:

```
[PXStringList(
         new [] { "SEASONAL", "PALLET", "1/4 TRKLD", "1/2 TRKLD", "FULL TRKLD", "COURTESY" },
         new [] { "SEASONAL", "PALLET", "1/4 TRKLD", "1/2 TRKLD", "FULL TRKLD", "COURTESY" })]
```

But, for some reason that I cannot see, the field does not show as a dropdown when I run the program.

Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please try to delete the fields from the Layout Editor and add it back and then publish the customization?

Comment: It is mandatory to delete and add the field back to change it's control editor type.

Answer (score 0):

SOOrderDiscountDetail.Description field attributes are not a good match for lists:

```
[PXDBString(256, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description")]
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<DiscountSequence.description, Where<DiscountSequence.discountID, Equal<Current<SOOrderDiscountDetail.discountID>>, And<DiscountSequence.discountSequenceID, Equal<Current<SOOrderDiscountDetail.discountSequenceID>>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
public virtual String Description { get; set; }
```

List are typically bound to a fixed size key field which is also missing. These attributes are what is expected on list fields:

```
[PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description")]
[PXStringList(new [] { "S", "P", "Q", "H", "F", "C" }, 
              new [] { "SEASONAL", "PALLET", "1/4 TRKLD", "1/2 TRKLD", "FULL TRKLD", "COURTESY" })]
public virtual String Description { get; set; }
```

Unless you wipe out existing data and rig the field to have a fixed combo box it would make more sense to create another custom field as Description attributes weren't meant to hold list.

Comment: Hughes, 
I've tried the code that you posted, but still, the field does not display as a ComboBox.
I'll create a custom to make it work.
Thanks for your help. 
Best,
Alfredo

Comment: Try Samvel comment too, he is right that controls needs to be re-created.